# LateX failed to create a dvi file. For possible explanations, start the command from the command prompt

Tags: errors

Could you please help me solving this problem
[image]

[image]

Comment: we can not debug screenshots very easily it is better to provide a small test document as text, and the error message from the log. However the document that you are using is apparently set up for pdflatex but you are using latex.

Comment: ... so either use pdflatex or if you have an option such as `\usepackage[pdflatex]{color}` remove the `pdftex` option as you are not using `pdflatex`